# How to get selected text from ListView and Adapter in Android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview, android-adapter

I have spent hours trying to figure this issue out and while I have come close, I am not getting the results I need. I have a messaging application that has a custom adapter and a listview with about 5 textviews. My issue is retrieving the text when a user long-presses on a message. After trying various methods, the closest I came was with:

```
        mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener( new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener
            (){


    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos, long id) {

        final String test = ((TextView)v).getText().toString();
        Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + test);


        return true;

        }
            });
```

The silly (read:frustrating) part about this code is that it works about 3-4 times successfully when clicked, however after that it force closes my application. The error I get is:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to  android.widget.TextView
 at android.widget.AbsListView.performLongPress(AbsListView.java:3347)
 at android.widget.AbsListView$CheckForLongPress.run(AbsListView.java:3294)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
```

The weird part is that I get the correct String of the message successfully the first few times, then it just doesn't want to work. After looking up the error, I tried cleaning the project multiple times, deleting the R.java file, and closing out Eclipse, but nothing has made a difference.

I have also tried using the position number of the messaging. The application never force closed when getting the position number of the message, however I couldn't get it to get the String that was attached to message at that location. The error was something about trying to convert from integer to string:

```
String test = ((EditText)av.getItemAtPosition(pos)).getText().toString();
```

My xml file consists of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="20dip"
    android:background="@drawable/bubble_yellow"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="invisible" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingBottom="1dip"
        android:paddingLeft="15dip"
        android:paddingRight="20dip"
        android:paddingTop="1dip"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingRight="20dip"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="20dip"
    android:background="@drawable/bubble_green"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="invisible" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="1dip"
        android:paddingLeft="15dip"
        android:paddingRight="20dip"
        android:paddingTop="1dip"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:paddingRight="20dip"
        android:text="TextView" />
   </LinearLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Update 1: Added requested xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background2"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:stackFromBottom="true" >
</ListView>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/sendMsgLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/messageText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Type Message"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:maxLines="3" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageSend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/send512" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Update2: My adapter contains the following:

```
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
 MessageModel array = data.get(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.message_item, null);
        viewHolder.left =(LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.left);
        viewHolder.right =(LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.right);
        viewHolder.txt1 = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        viewHolder.txt3 = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        viewHolder.txt2 = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        viewHolder.txt4 = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textView4);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
```

Update 3: Tried my best to follow @MDragon00's advice, unfortunately my app is still crashing when long pressing. I now have:

```
        mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener( new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener
            (){


    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos, long id) {


        TextView textView1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView textView2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView textView3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        TextView textView4 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView4);

        View.OnLongClickListener listener = new View.OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                TextView textView = (TextView) v;
                String text = textView.getText().toString();
                Log.i(TAG, "Text Selected = " + text);
                return false;
            }
        };

        textView1.setOnLongClickListener(listener);
        textView2.setOnLongClickListener(listener);
        textView3.setOnLongClickListener(listener);
        textView4.setOnLongClickListener(listener);

        return true;

        }
            }); 



}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The description of what each parameter does in onItemLongClick: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener.html

The issue here is that `av` is the **entire** ListView, while `v` is the **entire** row. Your row doesn't simply consist of a TextView, so you can't cast it to a TextView. In other words,

```
final String test = ((TextView)v).getText().toString();
```

isn't a good idea as the parent view is a RelativeLayout. A better solution would be to do the following:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.idOfTextView);
String text = textView.getText().toString();
```

As a small side suggestion, it sounds like you want to simply click on the item, not long click it. Use an OnItemClickListener instead of a OnItemLongClickListener if it suits your needs.

**Edit:**
According to your comments, the user will click/tap on a certain TextView out of several TextViews within some abstract row, and you want to get one of those four TextViews.

To do so, you'll need a new listener on each TextView. I can't give an exact answer without seeing your adapter, but when you inflate/get the row view to give to the ListView in the adapter, set an OnClickListener to the TextViews. For example with some pseudo-code:

```
// Get the textViews, to assign a listener to them
TextView textView1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
TextView textView2 = (Textview) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
..... // Etc and so on

// Create this listener anywhere, including via making the adapter/class
    // implement the listener and passing it in instead
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener(
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Get the view as a TextView, as this will only be used
            // with TextViews, so the only view to be passed
            // will be Textviews
        TextView textView = (TextView) v;

        // Do whatever with that text, or however you want to use the view
        String text = textView.getText().toString();
        someFunction(text);
    }
);

textView1.setOnClickListener(listener);
textView2.setOnClickListener(listener);
..... // Etc and so on
```

Now then, if you need the exact row that was clicked AND the text from an exact TextView, then you'll need to use both of the listeners [ie, one on the ListView and ones on the TextViews] to get the appropriate data.

**Edit Hopefully Final:**

```
public class TestAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context mContext;

    public TestAdapter (Context context, Data someData) {
        this.mContext = context;

        // Set up the data for your listView however
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return howManyRows;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return objectAtPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    } // Unnecessary, unless using databases

    // The listener for the textViews, feel free to use different listeners
    View.OnClickListener TextViewListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Get the view as a TextView, as this will only be used
            // with TextViews, so the only view to be passed
            // will be Textviews
            TextView textView = (TextView) v;

            // Do whatever with that text, or however you want to use the view
            String text = textView.getText().toString();
            someFunction(text);
        }
    };

    // Using the efficient pattern for recycling the views rather than using
    // findViewById repeatedly
    public static class ViewHolder{
        public TextView textView1;
        public TextView textView2;
        public TextView textView3;
        public TextView textView4;

        // And any other view that's part of the row view that you need
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = null;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView == null) {
            // Then gotta set up this row for the first time
            LayoutInflater inflater =
                    (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout.xml, parent, false);

            // Create a ViewHolder to save all the different parts of the row
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textView1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.textView2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            holder.textView3 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            holder.textView4 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView4);

            // Make the row reuse the ViewHolder
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else { // Otherwise, use the recycled view
            row = convertView;
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        // Set the current row's Textview onClickListeners
            // Note: You MAY be able to only set these once- feel free to set that
        holder.textView1.setOnClickListener(TextViewListener);
        holder.textView2.setOnClickListener(TextViewListener);
        holder.textView3.setOnClickListener(TextViewListener);
        holder.textView4.setOnClickListener(TextViewListener);

        // Set up the rest of the views however you need
            /*.....
              ......
             */

        return row;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, the (R.id.idOfTextView) is the problem with using your code in that I have more than one textview. For example, if I were to use "v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);" it would only work on a select few of the messages. I need it to work on all the messages.

Comment: Then use it with multiple lines, ie:
TextView textView1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
TextView textView2 = (TextView) v.findViewByID(R.id.textView2);
Etc. And just to be clear, you mean the text for only that row, not for the entire listView, correct?

Comment: Also, can you specify which xml is for your row/item, and post the xml for your listView [ie, the xml that contains the listView]? It may clear a few things up for me as well as anyone else who may come along

Comment: As requested, updated my other xml file. If I were to use multiple lines i.e. textView1, textView2, textView3, etc... how would I get the String from the necessary selected user?

Comment: Sorry for not replying earlier nor will I be able to reply in full until tomorrow, but a simple listener on the listView will NOT work as a solution. You'll need a bit of a more "complex" solution if your user is supposed to select a certain text view out of the four, and by more complex I mean outside of the scope of this question as is as it won't use a listener just on the listView. Will reply in full tmrw, but will take a listener around each textView if nothing else is to change

Comment: hi,if you use multiple textview or other control in your listview item then post your adapter class.

Comment: Edited, tell me if this works for you. Also, feel free to edit the question to further clarify that you have several TextViews in a single row, and want to get a click on a single one of those from a row

Comment: mDragon00, thank you for the help on this. I haven't tried your code yet, but I am working on it now. I went on ahead and updated the original post with what is in the Adapter for reference.

Comment: @MDragon00 Sorry, but I am having a lot of trouble with the code that you gave in your updated post. The "v" in the "v.findViewById" keeps giving errors (took them out to get it to work). The line with "View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener" keeps giving errors also, I'm still trying to change the code around, but my app keeps force closing. For reference, I updated the original post with the custom MessageAdapter.

Comment: I guess I should update my code with a full example. Unfortunately, I won't be able to start on it until 9 hours from now but what you're missing is that I said to add the listeners when you expand the rows inside the ListView's adapter. Ie, extend a BaseAdapter, set it up otherwise appropriately and efficiently, and when when setting up every row's view, THEN set the TextView's onClickListener. Sorry for being unclear. In the meantime, I suggest posting your FULL customized adapter (or as least the full function that gets returns each row), as I can't tell much with the small snipped of code.

Comment: Updated my answer. Remember, think over how it's done, as this isn't really pseudo-code but still needs to be edited for your case so that it works.

Comment: @steven How is it going? Any troubles with this?

Answer (score 0):

getItemAtPosition(pos) returns the view used as each of the item in the listView. According to your xml, the root element is RelativeLayout, so this method will return an RelativeLayout, not a TextView.
what you can do is:

```
String test = ((TextView)((View)av.getItemAtPosition(pos)).findViewById(R.id.textView1))
.getText().toString();
```

Comment: @user2429675 Tried your answer, however it gives me the following error: "Integer cannot be cast to a android.view.View"